# I am trying to setup Windows 7 as a VPN server

Tags: windows-7, vpn

My router is a Netgear N600 DGND3700.

On my router I have forwarded ports 1723 and 47 to the computer I am using as my VPN server.

Under WAN setup, I have selected the following options:

- Disable Port Scan and DoS Protection
- Respond to Ping on Internet Port
- NAT Filtering is set to 'Open'

Also, UPnP is turned off.

On my computer (Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit (Genuine Windows)), I went to Start, Control Panel, Network and Internet, Network and Sharing Center, Change Adapter Settings. Then I went to File -> New Incoming connection. I setup a user for VPN and ticked the 'Through the Internet' box under 'How will people connect?'

When I try to connect to my IP address from another location, it connects, authenticates, registers on the network and even shows up on my computer under 'Network Connections' for a second. Then it disconnects with error 733.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got the connection to assign an IP address by DHCP? Try giving it a fixed range of IP addresses and check they are not already in use by other devices on your network. I expect your router provides IP addresses?.

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid, thankyou!